# can a custom directive have both an isolated scope AND a "controller: ctrlName" field?

Tags: angularjs

If a directive has an isolated scope, will the controller field be taken into account ?

If yes, how does exactly the directive access this controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the isolated scope has nothing to do with the controller. Your problem is more of how to work with the controller (it use doesn't change in regard of the scope type).

A controller is useful when you want a directive to be required. If you have a directive called `menu` and another directive called `menu-item` and you want for example register all your `menu-item` in the `menu` directive, you create a controller.

When your `menu-item` does a `require: 'menu'` what it requires is the `menu` controller, not the directive itself.

Then you can have a directive like:

```
angular.module('app').directive('menu', function() {

   return {
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.foo = "foo";
         this.register = function(scope) {
            // register child here
         };
      }

});
```

`$scope.foo` can be accessed by `menu` template, but `this.register` can't.

When you require `menu` in your `menu-item` you can't access `$scope.foo` but you can access `this.register`.

**TL;DR;** Scope type and having a controller are not related.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/fzbSnhxN9rp4Ct5kvB9i?p=preview